# Instant notifications on my desktop

Tags: discussion, feature-request, notifications, notification-bar

I noticed the StackExchange button at the top-left of the screen which (on refresh) tells me everything that's going on as pertaining to me around the various sites. Is there anyway for me to get those notifications on my desktop or mobile device? If not, is there anyway for me to create that kind of app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [Stackapps](https://stackapps.com/), the SE site dedicated to the SE API and the apps created with it.  I'm pretty sure there is already an existing app to display notifications to the desktop.

Ah [here's one](https://stackapps.com/questions/290/stacktracker-cross-platform-desktop-notification-app).  And if you're a Gnome guy, [here's another](https://stackapps.com/questions/83/stackapplet-stackoverflow-meets-the-gnome-desktop-v1-4-released).

Comment: Thank you very much, Is there any documentation on said API?

Comment: However do you have one that shows just "my" notifications?

Comment: @Justin: Documentation: http://stackapps.com/questions/1/api-documentation-and-help; http://stackapps.com/questions/2/api-hello-world-code; http://stackapps.com/questions/3/sample-application-worlds-worst-stackoverflow-clone

Comment: @Justin: `However do you have one that shows just "my" notifications?` Why don't you look?  I gave you the link to the site.